# Does docker support command aliases similar to Git aliases?

Tags: git, shell, command-line, docker

I've been always struggling with docker when it comes to common tasks, like removing all `exited` containers, killing them or doing some maintenance tasks with docker images. Is there a way to define a docker command alias like we have in git, for example

```
[alias]
    last-commit = show --pretty=format: --name-only HEAD^{commit}
```

I would like to define a command to remove all exited containers, for example

instead of this

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -f status=exited -q)
```

I would like to do this

```
docker clean
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some ways to do. One easy way is to set function in your `.profile` or `.bashrc`

```
docker_clean() {

  docker rm $(docker ps -a -f status=exited -q)
}
```

then you can run `docker_clean` directly in shell.

There is a lot of projects in github you can refer to set `functions` or `alias`, here I list some of them.

[tcnksm/docker-alias](https://github.com/tcnksm/docker-alias/blob/master/zshrc)

[rossedman/docker.aliases](https://github.com/tcnksm/docker-alias/blob/master/zshrc)

Comment: That's a shame that Docker hav not introduced command aliasing already

Answer (score 0):

Docker does not have a separate support for aliases like git. Though, zsh alias can be used like:

`alias docker_clean="docker rm $(docker ps -a -f status=exited -q)"`